# How to create accdb file in vb 6.0 during runtime

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2007

Someone please help me to create MS Access database .accdb extension file during runtime using VB 6.0 at a particular location (e.g. E:\MMDataBase)
& also help me in creating tables in the same database.

MS Access 2007 is already installed in my computer

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACE database engine is essentially an extended version of Jet 4.0 and contains much of Jet 4.0 with support for the new format on top of that.  As a result both the SQL DML and DDL syntax is quite similar to Jet 4.0 SQL.

I'm not sure whether installing Access 2007 installs the ACE Provider or not.  Perhaps it is an optional item in the Access 2007 installer?  In any case a separate Microsoft download exists that can be used to install the necessary software even when you don't have Access 2007 at all.

See [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

Once that's in place the process is basically identical to doing this with Jet.  Example:

```
Private Sub CreateDB()
    'Reference required:
    '
    '   Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library (or later).
    '
    'OLEDB Provider required:
    '
    '   Access Database Engine 2007.

    Dim catDB As Object
    Dim cnDB As ADODB.Connection

    Set catDB = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
    With catDB
        .Create "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
              & "Data Source='D:\sample.accdb'"
        Set cnDB = .ActiveConnection
    End With
    Set catDB = Nothing
    With cnDB
        .Execute "CREATE TABLE ClassDates(" _
               & "Id IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_UID PRIMARY KEY," _
               & "Student TEXT(12) WITH COMPRESSION NOT NULL," _
               & "ClassDate DATETIME NOT NULL," _
               & "PaidFor YESNO DEFAULT False," _
               & "CONSTRAINT StudentDates UNIQUE (" _
               & "Student, ClassDate))", , _
                 adCmdText Or adExecuteNoRecords
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has helped me. if i have further queries i may come back to you.

Comment: I also thank you, it was helpful for my project.